# How to display densityplot kde value and histogram frequency value in same plot? Python, seaborn, jupyterlab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm trying to use seaborn to draw a histogram. Its simple either kde=True or false for density curve or simply a histogram. What I want is to be able to simply do something like

```
plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax2 = sns.distplot(data.length, hist=True, position=0)
ax = sns.distplot(data.length, kde=True)
plt.show()
```

But somehow get both the y label for the density curve on the left and histogram label values on the right. I've been trying to do this for over a hour playing around and can't figure out how to do something that should be so simple. Can you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to have separate axis for these? They are the same scale.

Comment: Yes I know. To clarify, I just want to be able to see the kde value on one side and the histogram frequency on the other. I can't seem to figure out how to do it and its driving me crazy. :(

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a [twin Axes](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html). Given this, you'll have to call plotting functions twice: once for histogram, another for kde.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.hist(...)
sns.kdeplot(..., ax=ax2)
```

No need to use `distplot` since you have to plot the histogram and kde separately.